# Finish request after ThreadPoolExecutor thread completes

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent, threadpoolexecutor, hystrix

I want to use a bulkhead in my Java Microservice. Half way through my service method I make an external HTTP request which is currently synchronous but want to execute that on a threadpool thread, I can do this using ThreadPoolExecutor. But after that new threadpool thread completes I want to continue on the original Tomcat thread through the rest of that method, which relies on data back from the threaded external request.  Is there a way I can keep the original thread and continue on with it using the data from the async thread?

Or are we typically looking at a code refactor here to deal with the rest of my method which relies on data back from the threaded request?

Comment: If you submit a Callable thread to the Executor it returns a Future, which can be evaluated at a later point in the code. But, if you need data back from the other thread, you will have to block execution at some point anyway.

Comment: @user3169180 Assuming I got you right, what benefit do you want to gain from running a synchronous call on separate thread, waiting for it and then proceeding with your main thread ? is resource management/limitation? queue management ? Anyways - the `Semaphore` class is your friend :)

Comment: I want to use a threadpool so I can use a timeout. Are you saying bulkheads are really only suitable for fire and forget tasks and not ones such as this which require further processing after?

Comment: Sorry but I am still unclear,  can I use a timeout with the semaphone approach? This I can do using a thread pool handoff. Again, not sure how to wait around on the tomcat thread until the threadpool thread finishes.

Comment: Actually, I assume I can wait using the future returned from the threadpool, then continue from that when the thread returns.

Comment: If all you want is a timeout, practically every HTTP library allows you to set a timeout.